# Why is the From email field not getting set?

Tags: php, html, captcha, recaptcha

Problem solved! Here is the final code:

```
<?php
    $full_name;$email;$subject;$message;$captcha;
        if(isset($_POST['full_name'])){
            $full_name=$_POST['full_name'];
        }if(isset($_POST['email'])){
            $email=$_POST['email'];
        }if(isset($_POST['subject'])){
            $subject=$_POST['subject'];
        }if(isset($_POST['message'])){
            $message=$_POST['message'];
        }if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
            $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
        }
        if(!$captcha){
            echo 'Check the reCAPTCHA box.';
            exit;
        }
        $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=SECRET-KEY-HERE&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
        if($response.success==false)
        {
            echo 'You are a robot!';
        }else
        {
            $to = "me@domain.com";
            $from = $full_name . ' <'.$email.'>';
            $headers = 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n";
            mail ($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

        echo 'Your message has been sent!';
        }
?>
```

Now I get the From field with the name of the sender + email address.

Thank you everyone for the help.

Comment: what do you get when you add var_dump($_POST) to your contact_form.php? Are you sure that the email value is getting passed to that form via POST ?

Comment: Also try moving this line:         $headers .= 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n"; out of the corresponding if statement and see if that helps. With your current logic, the from value will not be set if the captcha is not set.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're properly validating that you're receiving everything from $_POST. If it fails, you should trigger an error *each step of the way*.

In the code

```
if(isset($_POST['full_name']) && isset($_POST['full_name'])){
        $full_name = $_POST['full_name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $from = $full_name . '<'.$email.'>';
}
```

You're validating against $_POST['full_name'] twice; there's no isset() check on $_POST['email']. If $_POST['email'] isn't coming through properly, the from email address will be nulled out.

Answer (score -1):

First of all you don't have initializing $headers variable at all, but you have

> $headers .= 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n";

Initalize it on the beggining or just change operator ".=" into "=".

The next thing is that above concatenation will be execute only if field "g-recaptcha-response" will be exists in send $_POST array. As I can see there's no field with that name in that HTML code below. Try to add that field or remove this "if" statement

> if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']))

Answer (score -1):

I believe the issue may be the way that you're building the `from` variable:

```
$from = $full_name . '<'.$email.'>';
```

Notice that you have no space between the full name and the < character. Add a space in there and you should be good, i.e.:

```
$from = $full_name . ' <'.$email.'>';
```

As an aside, your code is not very well structured and has some logic flaws as commenters have mentioned. Consider restructuring it for your own sanity.